# Why does a long running docker instance fill up my disk space?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

When I launch a fresh Ubuntu machine (EC2) and download a single docker image which I run for a long time, after a couple weeks the disk fills up. How do I prevent this from happening?

Everything I find online talks about running docker prune, but my issue is not related to lots of stray docker images or volumes sitting around. This EC2 instance downloads a single image and launches it only once (and keeps it running forever, this is a CI runner).

Here are some clues:

- Both the host machine and the docker image are Ubuntu 20.04
- My EC2 instance has a 10 GB volume
- When I `docker pull` the image it's only 2.5 GB (it's an ubuntu minimal image)
- The boot script launches docker with this command:

`docker run -it -d --rm --shm-size=2gb --env --user root --name running-docker-ci ghcr.io/secret/docker-ci:latest start`

Here is the diagnosis I've done:

```
$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       10098432 10082048         0 100% /
devtmpfs         8192212        0   8192212   0% /dev
tmpfs            8198028        0   8198028   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            1639608   164876   1474732  11% /run
tmpfs               5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            8198028        0   8198028   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0         34176    34176         0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/3552
/dev/loop1         56832    56832         0 100% /snap/core18/1988
/dev/loop4         33152    33152         0 100% /snap/snapd/11588
/dev/loop5         56832    56832         0 100% /snap/core18/1997
/dev/loop6         72192    72192         0 100% /snap/lxd/19647
/dev/loop7         69248    69248         0 100% /snap/lxd/20326
/dev/loop2         32896    32896         0 100% /snap/snapd/11841
tmpfs            1639604        0   1639604   0% /run/user/1000
```

And running `du` a lot led me to this being my biggest folder:

```
/var/lib/docker$ sudo du -s * | sort -nr | head -50
13842100    overlay2
14888   image
128 containers
72  buildkit
56  network
28  volumes
20  plugins
20  builder
4   trust
4   tmp
4   swarm
4   runtimes
```

Any help? I'm stumped.

---

Add more details:

larsks Suggested maybe this is inside the container. It doesn't appear to be. I don't have anything running that generates files. Oddly I noticed that `df` shows 8 gigs are used by the `overlay` file system:

```
$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
overlay          8065444 8049060         0 100% /
tmpfs              65536       0     65536   0% /dev
tmpfs            8198028       0   8198028   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
shm              2097152      16   2097136   1% /dev/shm
/dev/root        8065444 8049060         0 100% /etc/hosts
tmpfs            8198028       0   8198028   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs            8198028       0   8198028   0% /proc/scsi
tmpfs            8198028       0   8198028   0% /sys/firmware
```

But when do `du` on the directory tree, it does not add up anywhere close to 8 gigs. I ran this from the root of the file system inside the running container:

```
$ sudo du -s * | sort -nr | head -50

3945724 home
1094712 usr
254652  opt
151984  var
3080    etc
252     run
192     tmp
24      root
16      dev
4       srv
4       mnt
4       media
4       boot
0       sys
0       sbin
0       proc
0       libx32
0       lib64
0       lib32
0       lib
0       bin
```

Comment: It looks like your image is running something that generates output in the filesystem. What is it? If you run your `du` inside the container, what directory is consuming the space?

Comment: That is something your image produce, most likely logs. If you go a bit further into `overlay2` directory, you will find what exactly. I recommend this sequence
`du -sch /var/lib/docker/overlay2/* | sort -h | tail` for further investigation.

Comment: @larsks It does not appear to be the file system insider the container. It's not generating any real output and running `du` confirmed this. However, I did find an odd discrepancy between `du` and `df`. I added details to the post above.

Comment: @anemyte Logs was a good theory! I dug into that a bit more and there are logs inside `/var/lib/docker/containers/*/*-json.log`. I ran this and determined I have 128 MB of log files.

`sudo find /var/lib/docker/containers -type f -name "*.log" -print0 | du -shc --files0-from - | tail -n1`

Comment: I found a github issue where some people are reporting the same issue, but it's mostly the blind leading the blind. No one has added a solution here for the `overlay2` directory growing: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/33775

Comment: What directory (or directories) inside the overlay2 directory are large? We can probably help you figure out to what they belong.

Comment: @larsks I'm not sure this is helpful, but these are the biggest sub directories:

```
/var/lib/docker/overlay2 $ sudo du -s * | sort -nr | head -5
9091236 c2170fa4c35a12507c5b3fe1e7ac2f42989cdb18096590d442cd29b1cab311a6
849704 ef6eb3c7239d8614e4d1d76fcdc651041e5656c4f0e12a1cb9c5b179972d9c25
727580 cba226c455e122c40608c0d9191a5cf94b37d692f4d9d99c61943396ed4262cd
592392 6229634eb87c05237a1612d10eced90c8e3b9b53db89c5561a5c1120a79e71d4
503476 9e7ce485ac85bec3f535fca064138b6db8100c762a312743fb27ef3729daddcc
```

Comment: Hmm, comments do not seem to support multi-line formatting. The point is that all the subdirectories are random alphanumerics.

Comment: I'm not sure how much else we can assist from here. If the disk usage is growing, you can examine the files and directories within the overlay2 directory to identify the ones using disk space. It's either going to be a growing container log or files written to the container filesystem. Because of how overlay filesystems work, df inside a container is just reporting the parent filesystem's free space.

Comment: @KeithSchacht : Please add the `--read-only` flag when executing `docker run`, if it truly does not generate any files then this should not impact you in any way and it may give us a better clue about where to look at.

Comment: @F1ko It does generate files, just nothing of substantial size. It's just pulling down a git repo then deleting it, pulling down and then deleting it. None of these files are particularly large.

Comment: After digging in more, I've had the idea to simply double the size of my disk space. From my reading up on how overlay2 works, I think that it's possible for the size of your disk to double what you think it is. Because overlay2 works by making a copy of the files each time you change one. So in theory, if every file in your image was changed, then you'd have a completely new copy of the filesystem (one in overlay2/diff and one in overlay2/original). My theory is: the file system is not growing unbounded, but it's growing up to 2x. We'll see if this solves it for me!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that part of how OverlayFS works is that delete operations don't always free up space in your filesystem. From [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/):

> - Deleting files and directories:

> When a file is deleted within a container, a whiteout file is created in the container (upperdir). The version of the file in the image layer (lowerdir) is not deleted (because the lowerdir is read-only). However, the whiteout file prevents it from being available to the container.

> When a directory is deleted within a container, an opaque directory is created within the container (upperdir). This works in the same way as a whiteout file and effectively prevents the directory from being accessed, even though it still exists in the image (lowerdir).

Without knowing your CI procedures it's hard to say precisely, but the point remains that if you think you're removing files, it's likely that the filesystem is retaining some or all of their contents.

Just as an aside, since you mentioned you're on AWS, you might consider a serverless CI deployment so that your container(s) starts from a clean slate on every run.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, seems like docker store too much images for some reason.

```
docker system prune --all --volumes --force
```

This command helps. Took for a while, but free up 80% of utilised space by images

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, that from the first look `overlay` (or `overlay2`) directory of Docker is to blame. However, from what I understand, it seems that the overlay directory is just an umbrella for whatever is inside the container.

What I did:

1. got into container shell: `docker exec -it <CONTAINER_ID> bash`
2. `du -sh /*` (you might need `sudo du -sh /*`
3. then traced which directories and files to the most space

Surprise surprise it was one big Laravel log file that took 24GB and exhausted all space on disk. You might have something similar.